# Can someone explain the following C++ Syntax?

Tags: c++, opencv, syntax

I recently came across a line that I do not quite understand in a C++ computer vision project someone else wrote. The project uses OpenCV library. The line is inside the constructor of a struct called Board.

```
struct Board {
    BoardID id;
    Origin origin;
    Vec<int> offset;
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> pattern;
    int n;
    // Rows and cols
    int nr;
    int nc;
    std::vector<std::vector<Vec<float>>> board;
    // ROI for saddle points detection
    const int img_rows;
    const int img_cols;
    cv::Mat roi;
    ...

    Board(BoardID _id, Origin ori, int imgr, int imgc): id(_id), origin(ori), img_rows(imgr), img_cols(imgc) { 
    ...
    roi = cv::Mat::zeros(img_rows, img_cols, CV_8U);
    ...
    // the line that I need help with understanding
    roi(cv::Rect(0, 0, img_cols*9/16, img_rows)) = true;
    ...
    ...
    }
```

Using the IDE's shortcut, I was able to extract the following information:
First, the definition of cv::Rect():

```
template<typename _Tp> inline
Rect_<_Tp>::Rect_(_Tp _x, _Tp _y, _Tp _width, _Tp _height)
    : x(_x), y(_y), width(_width), height(_height) {}
```

The definition of operator() overloading on cv::Mat:

```
inline
Mat Mat::operator()( const Rect& roi ) const
{
    return Mat(*this, roi);
}
```

The part that confuses me is the `= true;`. Why is the result of the `operator()`, which is technically a function applied on the `cv::Mat` `roi`, assigned a boolean value? What kind of C++ syntax is this?

Comment: I've never seen that before. The line appears to create a matrix of dimensions `x = 0`, `y = 0`, `width = img_cols*9/16`, `height = img_rows`, then it appears to set its pixels values to `true` (maybe `255`)? Can you check the matrix contents before and after `true` is set?

Comment: @eldesgraciado Hi! I did appear to have missed to include a line that is related to the matrix `roi` and have just updated the question.

Comment: Why don't you ask the author?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the documentation for OpenCV, it appears `cv::Mat` has an overloaded `operator=` that takes a scalar: see [this overload](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#aa5c947f7e449a4d856a4f3a87fcebd50). This overload writes the value on the RHS to all elements of the LHS matrix.

The other part of the key is that apparently copying a `cv::Mat` is a shallow copy: that is, no data is copied, just the structure.

As such, my belief is that your lines can be described as follows:

```cpp
// the part of the matrix we want to filter
cv::Rect filter = cv::Rect(0, 0, img_cols*9/16, img_rows)

// get a matrix referring to only the values corresponding to the above rect
cv::Mat filtered_matrix = roi(filter);

// write the value `true` to every element in our filtered section
filtered_matrix = true;
```

---

<sup>Take this with a grain of salt; I am not personally familiar with OpenCV.</sup>

Comment: Yes, that is essentially what is happening

Answer (score 2):

`roi` is a [`cv::Mat`](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html) whose values are initialized to 0.

`roi`'s [`operator()`](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a4272fce43d7405603fbb5e5f52580e57) is being called with a [`cv::Rect`](https://docs.opencv.org/master/dc/d84/group__core__basic.html#ga11d95de507098e90bad732b9345402e8) as input.  The return value is a new `cv::Mat` that *internally refers* to the specified subset of elements within `roi`.

Then [`operator=`](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#aa5c947f7e449a4d856a4f3a87fcebd50) is being called on that new `cv::Mat`, thus setting those elements to a value to 1 (`operator=` doesn't take a `bool`, but it does take a `cv::Scalar`, which can be constructed by implicitly converting the `bool` to a `double`).

Answer (score 1):

By doing the `cv::Rect(0, 0, img_cols*9/16, img_rows)`, you just obtain the first 9/16th columns of the image (all rows), with is then called a Region of interest (ROI).

By doing that, you are extracting a sub-mat from the `cv::Mat` called `roi`. And then using the assigment operator, you are then assigning `true` to all pixel of that new sub-mat.

We can divide the code like follow:

```
// 1) Extracting the sub-mat from the 'roi' one, and keep it as reference.
cv::Mat& sub_mat = roi(cv::Rect(0, 0, img_cols*9/16, img_rows));

// 2) Assign to all pixel of sub_mat the value true.
sub_mat = true;
```

Which means that at the end, roi is set to true on first 9/16 columns and left to 0 for the remaining 7/16.